# Tiny Linux Distro with JVM

Tags: linux, java, linux-distribution

I'm looking for a Linux Distro that has been stripped down completely with just the ability to install apps on it (particularly, a JDK). Any suggestions?

Definition of **tiny** in this case:
The minimum required to not get any errors while installing and running any version of the JDK.

Comment: Why not take puppy Linux, or Damn Small Linux, etc and just manually install the JDK?

Comment: I can't manage everything that's on a standard distro and I'm concerned about security. All I really want is what is required to install the JDK. I have tried `TinyCore` and `Alpine` so far. `Alpine` was cool but I had problems getting the JDK on there. `TinyCore` is cool too but has a really annoying mouse issue.

Comment: And small is important? You can't just take a very secure distro and add JDK if necessary? Do you have a definition for "small"?

Comment: @Hooli most distributions are tiny compared the size of even a cheap PC.  Where it makes a difference is in mobile and embedded devices.  Which sort of device do you have in mind?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Well, I want it specifically for the JVM which would imply any device. It would be great if it were on GitHub as well, none of the others seem to be. I tried the others and ran into multiple issues getting them going, they are all pretty much dead-ends. TinyCore x64 and x86 have bugs installing. Alpine does not like JVM. Pupply and DSL don't seem to have console-only versions which might imply they aren't that small. It's probably worth considering HP's [The Machine](http://fossforce.com/2014/12/hps-the-machine-the-future-of-linux/) as well in terms of memory management.

Comment: @Hooli This is the problem with tiny builds is that they often have something missing which prevents the code being up to date.  Maintaining a linux distro is a lot of work.

Comment: DSL = 50mB, Puppy = 100mB. Elliot Reed below says that Tiny Core Linux = 9mB. Now, could you please define "small"?

Comment: @Mawg: I didn't actually use the word "small" anywhere. However, my definition would be "the minimum required to not get any errors". In this case, while installing and running a JVM.

Comment: I'll also add then Debian, which is really secure and can be stripped down to a minimal during the installation process - it's also one of the easiest distros to install..

Comment: @ElliotReed: How big is Debian when stripped down to minimal? How many packages are installed? What's the overall size?

Comment: @Hooli I've set up a few small servers before and they've been around 500mb, but that's including lots of programmes and things you may not need. Damn Small Linux (DSL) was(/is) based on Debian and is around 50mb with a graphical desktop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of any specific ones with just the JVM on, however probably the smallest and easiest one to use is Tiny Core Linux. If you use the Core 9 version there's no graphical desktop and it's only around 9mb. You can find that here: http://tinycorelinux.net/

If you are more familiar with compiling packages and the Linux system in general, then you might want to try ttylinux - it's around 8mb! http://ttylinux.net/

Comment: He might as well use Gentoo & roll his own.

Comment: Or indeed Arch.. In fact Arch might be quite good in this case, if security is also a concern here..